# Add Properties after json load

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, http-get

I have this json:

```
{
"info": [
{
  "id": 999,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,

    },
    {
      "id": 2,
    }
  ]
}
]
}

Info
-- products
-----id
```

And my factory:

```
AppAngular.factory('model', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        load: function (scope) {
            $http.get('mydomain/api').success(function (data) {
                    var myObject = {};
                    angular.extend(myObject,data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < myObject.info.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < myObject.info[i].products.length; j++) {
                        myObject.info[i].products[j].selected = true;
                        myObject.info[i].products[j].quantity = 1;
                        .....
                       }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
} ]);
```

Theres is a way do add some property after angular.extend, without using a lot of for? We need do add some properties or behavior to the object after make json get.
For exemple:
`Info
    -- products
    -----id
    -----selected
    -----quantity`

Answer (score 2):

You could use angular.forEach:

```
AppAngular.factory('model', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        load: function (scope) {
            $http.get('mydomain/api').success(function (data) {
                var myObject = {};
                angular.extend(myObject,data);
                angular.forEach(myObject.info, function (info) {
                    angular.forEach(info.products, function (product) {
                        product.selected = true;
                        product.quantity = 1;
                        .....
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I'm looking for approach without iterate in my list. tks

Comment: Im not sure thats possible.. someone somewhere needs to look at every single product and add the entries.